# Problema al cambiar valores de variables en PHP usando codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Tengo un problema, mediante una función ajax envío al controller varios datos para guardarlos en una clase personal llamada Carrito, los datos llegan con normalidad, pero al intentar modificar los valores de las variables de la clase Carrito con los datos obtenidos de ajax, estos no se modifican.

Adjunto la clase Carrito

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Carrito{
        private $id;
        private $productos;
        private $headers;
        private $bodys;
        private $logos;
        private $headerLogos;
        private $bodyLogos;
        private $estado;
        private $pos;

        private function console($data){
            echo "<script>console.log('".$data."')</script>";
        }

        public function Carrito(){
            $this->id = array();
            $this->productos = array();
            $this->headers = array();
            $this->bodys = array();
            $this->logos = array();
            $this->headerLogos = array();
            $this->bodyLogos = array();
            $this->estado = array();
            $this->pos = 0;
        }

        public function add($headDatos, $bodyDatos, $headlogos, $bodylogos, $logo, $minimo, $producto){
            
            $headDatos = explode("|", $headDatos);
            $bodyDatos = explode("|", $bodyDatos);
            $cantidad = 0;
            $iter = 0;
            $head = count($headDatos);

            //Obtengo la cantidad del producto solicitado
            for($i = 0; $i < count($bodyDatos); $i++){
                $iter++;
                if($iter == $head){
                    $cantidad = $cantidad + $bodyDatos[$i-1];
                    $iter = 0;
                }
            }


            $respuesta = array();
            $respuesta['cantidad'] = $cantidad;

            //Verifico que la cantidad solicitada sea mayor o igual a la minima
            if($cantidad >= $minimo){
                //Agrego a los arreglos los datos para consultarlos posteriormente
                $this->id[$this->pos] = $this->pos;
                $this->productos[$this->pos] = $producto;
                $this->headers[$this->pos] = $headDatos;
                $this->bodys[$this->pos] = $bodyDatos;
                $this->logos[$this->pos] = $logo;
                $this->headlogos[$this->pos] = $headlogos;
                $this->bodyLogos[$this->pos] = $bodylogos;
                $this->estado[$this->pos] = 'A';
                $this->pos++;

                $respuesta['minimo'] = "Exito";
            }else{
                $respuesta['minimo'] = "Fracaso";
            }
            return $respuesta;
        }
    }
?>
```

Debería agregarse a los array los nuevos valores y la variable $pos aumentar pero no lo hace

Adjunto el método en AJAX

```
function agregarCarrito(hd, bd, hl, bl, isLogo, minimo, producto, route){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: route + "index.php/tiendavirtual/agregarCarrito",
        data: {tbldatosHead: hd, tbldatosBody: bd, tbllogosHead: hl, tbllogosBody: bl, logo: isLogo, minimo: minimo, producto: producto},
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(respuesta){
            if(respuesta['minimo'] == "Fracaso"){
                pushMensaje("fallo", "Error!", "Este producto requiere una compra minima de "+minimo+".", route);
            }
            //$("#btnMasOpciones").prop("type", "submit");
            //$("#btnMasOpciones").click();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            errorAjax(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            alert('Error al agregar al carrito de compras');
        }
    });
}
```

La comunicación entre javascript y la clase Carrito se da por medio del controller, con esta función

```
public function agregarCarrito(){
        $data['user'] = $_SESSION['user'];
        $headDatos = $this->input->post("tbldatosHead");
        $bodyDatos = $this->input->post("tbldatosBody");
        $headlogos = $this->input->post("tbllogosHead");
        $bodylogos = $this->input->post("tbllogosBody");
        $logo = $this->input->post("logo");
        $minimo = $this->input->post("minimo");
        $producto = $this->input->post("producto");

        $result = $this->carrito->add($headDatos, $bodyDatos, $headlogos, $bodylogos, $logo, $minimo, $producto);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

¿Alguna idea del porqué las variables sólo se modifican en el método pero cuando las llamo desde otro método están vacías?

Gracias.

Comment: No entendí en que parte hace la modificación ?

Comment: La modificación se hace en la función add de la clase Carrito